# How does Hyperledger-fabric confirms the user as a valid user in the network?

Tags: transactions, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, pki

I know that a user must get an identity created by Certificate Authority(CA) before they join Hyperledger Fabric Network. The CA will create a public key and a private key to the user. When the user submits a transaction to the peer node in the network, the transaction will be signed using private key and the peer node will confirm the transaction by using public key of the user to confirm the transaction is initiated by a user that had gone through CA first(Correct me if my understanding is wrong).

For example in a network there is OrgA, Org B and Org C. Org A has 100 peer nodes and 1,000,000 user. If each of those 100 peer nodes has to keep 1,000,000 user's public key, isn't it kind of a waste of database resources because each of them has to keep those 1,000,000 user's public key and information when most probably they could divide the keeping of public key since these peer nodes are from the same organization?

Answer (score 0):

Every channel is a distinct ledger. For every Channel, there is an Organization MSP(Crypto Material) which holds a Root Certificate for this Organization's CA. The MSPs (along with other stuff like permissions and access controls) for every organization are stored in the ledger and its called channel configuration.

Now, when a user makes a transaction, using PKI (Public Key Infrastructure) a node checks that the user's certificate is signed by the root certificate that is specified in the channel configuration for this Organization.

So this: "If each of those 100 peer nodes has to keep 1,000,000 user's public key" is not true. The nodes do not hold user credentials like CAs. The nodes only host the ledger and a Database which holds the latest key value pairs of the ledger for fast performance on queries.

Note that the Fabric CA and the Fabric Network (Channels, Nodes) are two distinct components. Inside the Channel Configuration, one can use any certificates from any CA they want if they already have a CA component.

So bottom line is, nodes do not hold user credentials, users are not validated via CA when making transactions, and the peers do not speak with the CA for validation. The root certificate of the organizations CA is stored in the Channel configuration on the ledger and every user's certificate is verified using this root of trust.

Answer (score -1):

Hyperledger Fabric uses an abstraction called [msp](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/msp.html) to maintain and validate membership of users. It is usually a folder structure on filesystem, which maintains keys and certs. The PKI keys don't take much space. For your question regarding peers, different peers of an organization can have different responsibilities, some can be configured like endorsing peers, committing or admin peers.